# Getting an undefined local variable error in Ruby when debugging

Tags: ruby, debugging

I have the following script in a file called `foo.rb`

```
def foo(msg)
  msg
end

def bar
  thing = 123
  thing
end

debugger
p foo(:hai)
```

I run the program in debug mode, like so:

```
ruby --debug -r debug foo.rb
```

Notice I make sure the stdlib `debug` is loaded via `-r` and I also put the ruby environment into debug mode using `--debug`

So the first output I get is unexpected:

```
Debug.rb                                                                                                                          
Emacs support available.                                                                                                          

/Users/M/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:57:        RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter
```

After that, if I press `c` to 'continue' the program ends with the following error:

```
Exception `NameError' at foo.rb:10 - undefined local variable or method `debugger' for main:Object foo.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `debugger' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to actually get debug mode to recognise the relevant `debugger` command (if that's even the correct command to be using; the docs aren't clear at all on this)

Note: I'm not interested in using 3rd party gems in this instance (e.g. pry or ruby-debug). I'm only interested in understanding how to use the stdlib debugger that comes with Ruby

### Update

Since this question was answered, I've gone ahead and created a gist for future reference. For anyone stumbling across this thread you might find it useful: https://gist.github.com/Integralist/5658cb218bb50494a1fa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-r`. The entire mechanism by which an interactive debugging sessions is loaded is by the literal line of code [`require 'debug'`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html).

Your code should look like this:

```
def foo(msg)
  msg
end

def bar
  thing = 123
  thing
end

require 'debug'
p foo(:hai)
```

And you should run the program by simply typing `ruby <program_name>.rb`.